# Why are my numbers in Pycharm purple, and my "=" orange?

Tags: pycharm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cV7B.png)I did something and now everything's messed up :( . And now Pycharm says their are never errors as well. Also, when tabbing over it doesn't automatically indent the code when i'm using anything like for, if, or any of the above.

i haven't done anything because i don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

This is just regular syntax highlighting, it was made to make looking and understanding the code easier. I believe there is a option to disable this if you wish, review the settings page. It also might be a good idea to ask this question in a community focused on pycharm.